# 'pylint' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt, pylint

I am on Windows 10.

I installed the "pylint" package with the command `pip install pylint --user` and it successfully got installed.

But when I try to run the command in command prompt,I am getting the  `'pylint' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
I checked the path and it is installed with all the other python packages.How do I solve this?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Make sure `site.USER_BASE` as mentioned in the docs is in your `PATH`: https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: can you install the package for all users?

Comment: Which command did you execute?

Comment: I tried to run "pylint filename.py". and Pylint is intalled for all users

Comment: You should read the notice in `pylint` documentation about usage on windows platform: https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/installation.html#note-for-windows-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work

1. search for "edit the system environment variables" in search.
2. click environment variables.
3. under "system variables" click "path" and click edit.
4. click "new".
5. go back and copy the path where python package(pylint) is installed and paste it there.
6. click ok everything.
7. check now it works...

Comment: This worked(windows). In step 5, I added `python's scripts` folder in my env variables system's path. for me the scripts folder was located at `C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts`


[reference here](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/installation.html#:~:text=C%3A%5CPythonDirectory%5CScripts%5C).

Answer (score 14):

The following command worked for me:

```
py -m pylint file.py
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I'm in windows10

Answer (score 0):

The below command has taken from the first answer but works fine for the new python version

```
python3 -m pylint <File_Name>
```