# What to do about bash: pigar: command not found error?

Tags: python, bash

I'm using pigar to try and generate a requirements file from a Jupyter notebook.

However when doing the following I'm running into an error:

I've pip installed pigar and checked the python version on bash:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.2
```

However, when running the following command:

```
 pigar -c ./requirements.txt
bash: pigar: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you "pip installed pigar", the details matter. Was a virtualenv active? Figure out _where_ it got installed. Where did the `pip` binary you ran come from? Did it end up somewhere under `$HOME` that isn't currently in your `PATH`? Etc.

Comment: Right now there's not enough information in the question for it to be possible to provide a canonically correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tried referring this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63565649/13267627).

```
py -m pigar -c ./requirements.txt
```

worked for me

Comment: Thanks for the solution and effort but this does not worked for me, but, changing it to `python3 -m pigar generate` was enough for me and worked well.